# Rate of change: Simplifying the expression

Tags: calculus

For the function $f(x)=x^3-8x+3$, calculate $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$  where $a = 5$ and

a. $h = 2$

b. $h = 1$

c. $h = 0.5$

d. $h = 0.1$

Simplify the expression before substituting.

I don't know how I should set it up to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(a + h)^3 - 8(a + h) + 3 - (a^3 - 8a + 3)}{h} = \frac{a^2 + 3a^2h + 3ah^2 + h^3 - 8a - 8h + 3 - a^3 + 8a - 3}{h} = 3a^2 + 3ah + h^2 - 8$$

Answer (score 0):

It might have been more clear if the book would have written the difference quotient using $x$ as the variable instead of $a$.

Because you are not asked to calculate the difference quotient for some arbitrary $h$, this actually makes life a lot easier. It's really just a "plug and chug" problem. To get started, substitute the values for $h$ and $a$.

$$\frac{f(5+2)-f(5)}2=\frac{f(7)-f(5)}2$$

Find the value of the function at these points, and carry out the operations.

Answer (score 0):

What it means that is that you should algebraically simplify the expression
$$
\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} = \frac{(a + h)^3 - 8(a + h) + 3 - (a^3 - 8a + 3)}{h}
$$
*before* you substitute specific values $a$, $h$.